# For each item (of a class) on the stage, add each item to an array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, function, timeline

trace(listOfCells)I don't understand how to do this. I currently have this code on the timeline:

```
var listOfCells:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int =0; i < stage.numChildren; i++)
{
    listOfCells.push(stage.getChildAt(i));
}

trace(listOfCells)
```

How would one type a code that adds each item of a class to the array? Because when I trace the array, it only says [object MainTimeline] once, not twice (I have two identical movieclips on the stage).

The reason for all this is so I can compare each movieclip's x and y value to every other one, and then move toward each other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing right. To access the objects inside the array, again you need to loop through it . Try this,

```
var listOfCells:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int =0; i < this.numChildren; i++)
{
    listOfCells.push(this.getChildAt(i));
}

var len:int = listOfCells.length;
for (var j:int =0; j < len; j++)
{
    trace(listOfCells[j].x);
}
```

or you can access the root of the application to get the elements like below,

```
var listOfCells:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int =0; i < (root as MovieClip).numChildren; i++)
{
    listOfCells.push((root as MovieClip).getChildAt(i));
}

trace(listOfCells)

var len:int = listOfCells.length;
for (var j:int =0; j < len; j++)
{
    trace(listOfCells[j].x);
}
```

Comment: It seems to trace a 0, even if I have two cells on the stage?

Comment: what is your result for trace(stage.numChildren); ??

Comment: Hm... 1! If I type: 
{
    trace(stage.numChildren);
}

Comment: So you have one element on stage. It might have two child elements which you are seeing on stage.

Comment: I am a bit confused.

I made a shape into a movieclip called Cell, then I added two Cells to the stage.

The Cells themselves have a lot of other movieclips inside them, but that's just for the animation they have. The other movieclips inside them have other names.

Comment: I drag them manually (I will do the adding through code in a later stage of the game). So I guess I have two instances of the same movie clip.

Comment: can you check the instance name of the Cells whether they are same??!!

Comment: They don't have any instance names :p

Comment: Then ensure that there are 2 instances of Cell on the stage !

Comment: But if I would use code to add the cells, then I couldn't give them any instance names (since the amount of cells added through code would always be random). So is there any way to do this without naming the cells?

Comment: There are two instances of the cells on the stage, but they have no instance names. You know, where it says "<Instance Name>".

Comment: You're the best, Subash. Thank you so much for everything you have done.